# How to segregate rows in Hive?

Tags: hive

I would like to achieve what `NTILE` does but not by passing the number of buckets but passing the number of items in each bucket. Is there a way to do this in Hive?

So `NTILE(2)` will give you

```
StudentID       MARKS       NTILE  
      S5           93           1 
      S3           91           1 
      S2           83           1
      S4           83           2
      S1           75           2
```

I want to achieve the same but not by passing the number of buckets(=2), but passing the number of items I need in each bucket(=3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a clue from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279341/dynamic-parameter-for-ntile-sql-function). This can be achieved using `ROW_NUMBER` like below,

```
SELECT
    StudentID
    ,MARKS
    ,CEIL(ROW_NUMER() OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY MARKS DESC)/3) as segment
FROM
    table_name;
```